# Fixing double-encoded utf-8 returned by Requests

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, python-requests

I'm retrieving an Atom response using `Requests`, and encountering an encoding issue:

When I retrieve it using curl, it's correct, showing the Ä:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:zapi="http://zotero.org/ns/api">
<title>The power broker : Robert Moses and the fall of New York</title>
(snip)
<content zapi:type="citation" type="xhtml">
    <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">(Robert Ä. Caro 1974)</span>
</content>
</entry>
```

But when I retrieve it using requests 2.2.1 on Python 2.7.4, I get this unicode response:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url)
r.text
u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:zapi="http://zotero.org/ns/api">
<title>The power broker : Robert Moses and the fall of New York</title>
(snip)
<content zapi:type="citation" type="xhtml">
    <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">(Robert \u0102\x84. Caro 1974)</span>
</content>
</entry>'
```

Of course, encoding this as utf-8 doesn't give me my Ä back. What do to?

Comment: Can you add your `requests` code?

Comment: @Drewnes Ooops, sorry. Done.

Comment: Try `r.content` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have any response headers sent by the server included I can't really conclude this, but what I am guessing is that the server sent back utf8 encoded string with a header with the wrong charset set:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

So that request will treat that as a stream of bytes (or str in python2) and decode that string based on that charset into a unicode string.  Reencode the unicode into latin1 and decode back into utf8 should get back the original string.

```
r.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf8')
```

But yeah, use r.content and you get back a `str` type and you can apply the correct encoding manually by decoding it into utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not curl trying to create a "known" letter to replace the seldon used "Ă"  that `\u0102` is? Googling for this authors name, the "A" should be just plain (Robert Allan Caro) . The u"\x84" char, itself is a closing quote unicode char - (check http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/list.htm) - so this could be an OCR artifact from scanning "Robert "A." Caro" from somwhere - represented in the server just as you are seeing it on the Python side.

Try using curl with the `--raw` option to check the actual content in this case.

(I've played around with the string, and this hipoteses look more probable to
me than double-encoding in this case).

Comment: No, I created the record with the Ä so it would be returned like that for testing purposes. Robert Caro is in reality Robert A. Caro – sorry for the confusion.